# Put one symbol into another

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I'm curious how I can make a custom character, more specificlly I want to inscribe equal sign into different shapes like circle, trianle and whatever I want. Is it possible to do that without `tikz` package?
[image]

*Here is an example of what I want (I made it using image editor just to show).*

Comment: You will have to be able to create the appropriately sized outer figure (without `tikz` you say).  Then, you could use `stackengine` as `\stackinset{c}{}{c}{<v-shift>}{$=$}{$<my outer shape>$}`

Comment: Have a look at the `circledsteps` package. It gives you the circled text right away, and shows you what you can do for the other shapes. `tcolorbox` also can give you these but probably it does not count as "no Ti*k*Z".

Comment: Example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.2ex}{$=$}{$\bigcirc$}

\stackinset{c}{.03ex}{c}{-.15ex}{$=$}{\scalebox{1.25}{$\square$}}

\stackinset{c}{.03ex}{c}{-.15ex}{$=$}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}%
  {\scalebox{1.25}{$\square$}}}
\end{document}`

Comment: You can also overlap characters using `\rlap`, `\llap` and `\makebox[0pt]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, or at least a partial one. It defines an `\inscribedeq` command, which takes as a mandatory argument the symbol in which the equal sign should be inscribed. It also takes two optional arguments which allow to fine-tune the look of the result:

- The first optional argument is a length by which the symbol is raised;
- The second one is a factor by which the symbol is scaled.

Here are a few examples with symbols from `MnSymbol`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlength{\eqwidth}
\newlength{\symbwidth}
\newlength{\maxwidth}
\settowidth{\eqwidth}{\(=\)}
\NewDocumentCommand{\inscribedeq}{O{0pt} O{1} m}{%
    \settowidth{\symbwidth}{\scalebox{#2}{\(#3\)}}
    \ifdim \eqwidth > \symbwidth
        \let\maxwidth\eqwidth
    \else
        \let\maxwidth\symbwidth
    \fi%
    \mathrel{%
        \raisebox{#1}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\scalebox{#2}{\(#3\)}}}%
        \makebox[\maxwidth]{\(=\)}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\( x \inscribedeq{} y \)                & \( x \inscribedeq{\largecircle} y \)                  \\
\( x \inscribedeq{\largesquare} y \)    & \( x \inscribedeq[.1pt][1.1]{\largetriangleup} y \)   \\
\( x \inscribedeq{\largediamond} y \)   & \( x \inscribedeq{\circlearrowleft} y \)              \\
\( x \inscribedeq{\bigcup} y \)         & \( x \inscribedeq[-1pt][1.5]{\largestar} y \)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```